# Form processing: How to process form before output and access data from shortcode

Tags: shortcode, forms

I have a form that's output with a shortcode. I need to be able to conditionally process a redirect on the form submission, so the form processing needs to happen before any output is sent (I've put it on the `init` hook).

What's the best way for me to access the form validation's status (`$validate`) so I can output any errors that are found in the form (within the shortcode)? Is using a global variable the only way? I try to avoid that if possible. I will have multiple forms needing to use this same process as well.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_process_my_form' );
function wpse_process_my_form() {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['submit'] ) && 'myform' == $_POST['submit'] ) {
        if ( $validate = wpse_validate_my_form( $_POST['form_data'] ) ) {
            $success = wpse_save_my_form( $_POST['form_data'] );
            if ( $success ) {
                wp_redirect( '/success', 302 );
                exit();
            }
        }

    }
}

add_shortcode( 'myform', 'wpse_my_form_shortcode' );

function wpse_my_form_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // Somehow get the errors ($validate) generated in the function attached to init

    // output form (with errors if found)

    return $form;
}

function wpse_save_my_form( $form_data ) {
    // Run save process here, return true if successful 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, a good one I think, is to use a object with a property to store the validation status so you set the value of this property in the init action hook where you process the form and access to it in the shortcode. For example:

```
class MyForm {

    private $validate;

    function __construct() {
         add_shortcode( 'myform', array($this, 'wpse_my_form_shortcode') );
         add_action( 'init', array($this, 'wpse_process_my_form') );
    }

    function wpse_my_form_shortcode( $atts ) {
        // Somehow get the errors ($validate) generated in the function attached to init

        $output = '';

        // output form (with errors if found)
        if( $this->validate['success'] == 'error' ){
             $output .= '<div class="error">'.$this->validate['message'].'</div>';
        }
        $output .= '<form name="my_form" method="post">';
        $output .= '<input type="text" name="form_data">';
        $output .= '<button type="submit">'.__('Submit').'</button>';
        $output .= '</form>';

        return $output;

    }

    function wpse_process_my_form() {
        if( isset($_POST['form_data']) ) {
            $this->wpse_validate_my_form( $_POST['form_data'] );
            if ( $this->validate['success'] == 'success' ) {
                $success = $this->wpse_save_my_form( $_POST['form_data'] );
                if ( $success ) {
                    wp_redirect( '/success', 302 );
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function wpse_save_my_form( $form_data ) {
        // Run save process here, return true if successful
        return true;
    }

    function wpse_validate_my_form( $data ) {

        $validation = array();

        if( $data == 'validate_me' ) {
            $validation['success'] = "success";
            $validation['message'] = "the success message";
        } else {
            $validation['success'] = "error";
            $validation['message'] = "the error message";
        }

        $this->validate = $validation;

    }

}
new MyForm();
```

Note: It is a quick example to show you the point.